# Is it possible to display business catalyst analytics on your front end?

Tags: analytics, business-catalyst

I'm just wondering if there is a module tag in Business Catalyst which will enable me to display the visitor count and page views automatically on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a module that will allow you to view that data on the frontend of a site.

You could run a report and then upload that PDF to a page if you are looking to allow certain users access to visitor data without allowing backend access.

The other option would be to find an analytics provider that has an API or some method of allowing you to display this data on the frontend of your site.